# How to declare an extra dependency on an existing Gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, swagger, openapi

Gradle 8.1 (Android Studio Giraffe) [requires explicit or implicit dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency) between tasks. If I am generating resources destined to be packaged up by the Android Gradle Plugin with i.e. some OpenAPI tool, I don't understand how I can augment the existing Gradle task owned by the Android Gradle Plugin, as per the hints offered by Gradle:

```
Possible solutions:
  1. Declare task ':app:generateOpenApiFooBar' as an input of ':app:packageDebugResources'.
  2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:generateOpenApiFooBar' from ':app:packageDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn.
  3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:generateOpenApiFooBar' from ':app:packageDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter.
```

Is there a way to get to the existing 'packageDebugResources' task and add a dependency on my plugin? Something like the following (which does not work in any variation I have tried):

```
tasks.named('packageDebugResources').dependsOn generateOpenApiFooBar
```

Comment: The most up-to-date relevant info I could find: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46466/Kotlin-MPP-publishing-Gradle-7-disables-optimizations-because-of-task-dependencies but a bit specific, still not clear how/why this dependency needs to be declared

Comment: You can use the project.tasks property to get a reference to all of the tasks in your project. Then, you can use the dependsOn method to add a dependency on your plugin task.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in an `afterEvaluate`, or better yet, use the `androidComponents` API:

```kotlin
androidComponents {
  onVariants { variant ->
    tasks.named("package${variant.name.replaceFirstChar(Char::uppercaseChar)}Resources")
      .dependsOn("generateOpenApiFooBar")
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that the Android Gradle Plugin registers all tasks in the `afterEvaluate` phase of configuration so if you simply try to find a task using `tasks.named` before this phase, you'll get a `UnknownTaskException` exception.

The original warning usually happens when a task incorrectly generates sources that are an input for another task.
For example, some tasks generates output directly into an existing input directory for another task. This is bad because Gradle has no way of knowing that it needs to run your task before the compile task.

Instead they should write their output to their own directory and then add this directory as a source directory for the source sets. It's important you don't add the directory directly to the source set but rather use a property that is attached to the task so that Gradle knows who generates those files (`srcDir(myTaskProvider.flatMap { it.outputDirectory })` or something like that).

When using Android, they have an API for registering source generating tasks. You can use it like this:

```kotlin
@Suppress("LeakingThis")
abstract class BuildConfigTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:Input
    abstract val packageName: Property<String>

    @get:Input
    abstract val variantName: Property<String>

    @get:OutputDirectory
    abstract val outputDirectory: DirectoryProperty

    init {
        // This prevents changing the value after it's been read
        packageName.finalizeValueOnRead()
        variantName.finalizeValueOnRead()

        // This is set automatically by the Android Gradle Plugin
        outputDirectory.finalizeValueOnRead()
    }

    @TaskAction
    fun generateStuff() {
        outputDirectory.get()
            .also { it.asFile.deleteRecursively() }
            .file("${packageName.get().replace('.', '/')}/BuildConfig.kt")
            .asFile
            .also { it.parentFile.mkdirs() }
            .writeText("""
                package ${packageName.get()}
                
                object BuildConfig {
                  val variant: String = "${variantName.get()}"
                }
            """.trimIndent())
    }
}

androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
        val task = tasks.register<BuildConfigTask>("generate${variant.name.replaceFirstChar(Char::uppercaseChar)}BuildConfig") {
            packageName.set(android.namespace)
            variantName.set(variant.name)
        }
        // This can be `.java` even if you're generating Kotlin code
        variant.sources.java?.addGeneratedSourceDirectory(task, BuildConfigTask::outputDirectory)
    }
}
```

Running `./gradlew assembleDebug` will generate this file in `build/generated/java/generateInternalDebugBuildConfig/com/example/BuildConfig.kt`:

```kotlin
package com.example

object BuildConfig {
  val variant: String = "debug"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project.tasks property to get a reference to all of the tasks in your project. Then, you can use the dependsOn method to add a dependency on your plugin task.

```
project.tasks['packageDebugResources'].dependsOn('generateOpenApiFooBar')
```